# Setting in Chrome browser to enable data sources access across domains

Tags: google-chrome

Normally browsers block data sources access across domains
in IE we can enable it by change this setting (under security tab, click local intranet and then custom level)

[image: data access across domains - IE setting]

If I have to enable the same thing in Chrome how will I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)